# document.querySelector causing errors on other methods when called

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

My apologies for the stupid question, but I am trying to change the name of a button upon uploading a file. My code to change it is this, via TypeScript:

```
    const i = (document.querySelector('label') as any).innerText = filename;
```

The code above, inside the `fileName` method, changes the "Upload Project File" text into the name of whatever file that is uploaded.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="clg6 cmd8 csm10 cxs12" v-if="this.projectFile">
        <button 
          class="button primary outline medium upload">
          <label>
            <input 
            type="file"
            name="projectFile"
            id="fileName"
            accept=".xls, .xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel" 
            v-on:change="validateFileType(); hashContentMD5(); fileName; getPresignedURL()"/>
              <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload"></i> 
              Upload Project File
          </label>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And it works. However, upon change, it brings up errors in my other methods when they're called, such as this:

```
const file = (document.getElementById('fileName')as any).files[0]
```

The error that shows up is

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')
```

Removing the `document.querySelector` removes the error. This is the first time that I've encountered this. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use `ref` instead of `document.querySelector`?

Comment: My apologies, I may lack a bit of sleep -- how would that look like? @LucasDavidFerrero

Comment: Do not access DOM directly in Vue, unless you have to (here you don't), certainly not through selectors. You could access input value through events instead of accessing an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems:

You put your `input` inside the `label` tag. I learned this is okay.

1. Why using a `button` outside the whole `label` and `input` tags? I don't understand what your intention was with that.
2. You replace the inside of the `label` tag by a text node (containing the file name). Through your replacement you delete your `input` field out of the DOM. See `querySelector` line in your code.
3. After having replaced the input field, there is no `fileName` on the page anymore, so it `getElementById` results in `null`.

Solution:

1. (optionally) I'd delete the `button` tag and only keep the inside of it.
2. Don't operate on that `label` and don't try to overwrite the value of a file `input` field
3. By not removing the `input` field anymore, you can access it and read out the file name

See my example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fdxxnf

Comment: Whats wrong with input in label?

Comment: It's not wrong to put `<input>` inside `<label>`. Just another way of label association without using an ID.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, you're right, I didn't use a label that way until today.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `ref`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      projectFile: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLbl() {
      this.$refs.lab.innerText = 'filename'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="clg6 cmd8 csm10 cxs12" v-if="projectFile">
        <button 
          class="button primary outline medium upload">
          <label ref="lab">
            <input 
            type="file"
            name="projectFile"
            id="fileName"
            accept=".xls, .xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel" 
            v-on:change="changeLbl"/>
              <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload"></i> 
              Upload Project File
          </label>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```